# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' in maths

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am writing math related code. The code has to give you the area of Circle, Square or Triangle. I am stuck on how you write cm2 in the end, in answer. The code is working but I need to add somehow cm2 in answer. I tried, but I get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

```
r = input("Please insert radius in cm:")
r_float = float(r)
pindala1 = pi * r_float ** 2
print(pindala1 + "cm^2")
```

The result should be for example `5 cm^2`.

Comment: You have to format `pindala1` as a string, `print(str(pindala1) + " cm^2")` or `print("{} cm^2".format(pindala1))`

Answer (score 0):

`pindala1` is a `float` and you can't add a `float` with a `str`, use a comma to separate the arguments of the `print` function by a `' '`:

```
print(pindala1, "cm^2")  #  =>  '5 cm^2'
```

Or, not as good as the one above, you can use addition, but convert to `str` first and manually add the `' '`:

```
print(str(pindala1) + " cm^2")  #  =>  '5 cm^2'
```

You can also use `format`ting, which comes in handy for these kind of tasks:

```
print("{} cm^2".format(pindala1))  #  =>  '5 cm^2'
```

Comment: For Python 3.6 and above, you can also use f-strings.